# Make a byobu window use a smaller font than the other byobu windows of the same session

Tags: fonts, byobu

I have a Byobu open in Ubuntu, with two "windows" (sort of tabs) inside.

Is it possible to reduce the font size in the first, while leaving the second at standard font size?

For instance, in a gnome-terminal with two tabs open, I would press `CTRL -` and that would only affect the font size of that particular tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, that's not possible.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*